# How Thread.join() internally works

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering if anybody can point me some detailed documentation on how Java's thread join method internally works. I understand that if you use thread.join() then it makes parent thread to wait for the child thread but I am more interested on the implementation aspect of it.

I kind of have a rough understanding (not sure how much correct it is), I believe when parent thread calls join method, it internally calls wait on some object(this?) and when child thread completes it may fire a notifyAll() on the same object.

Can any body confirm this or point me to any detailed documentation here ?
Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly won't find any 'detailed documentation' for a method that only runs 24 lines in the source code. Have a look.

Comment: [Source code if you are interested](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.join%28long%29)